# How to create dictionary with duplicate keys out of a column in python

Tags: python, dictionary, split, duplicates

I have two columns like this:

```
    AB       A
    AD       B
    AB*AF    D
    CD*EG    E
    CG*AB    H
```

I try to create a dictionary with the first column by splitting the values as keys and values with the delimiter '*'. There are duplicates that should not be deleted since the combinations are different. In addition, I need to compensate the values that are not combined with other values by using empty values.
This is my code:

```
for x in lines:
    firstVal.append(x.split('   ')[0].split('*')[0])

    if '*' in x:
            secondVal.append(x.split('  ')[0].split('*')[1])

#to add empty values to create correct pairs (not the best way to compensate empty values!)
count = 0
while (count < 5):     
    count = count + 1
    secondVal.insert(0, '')

#to create pairs 
dictPairs = dict(zip(firstVal, secondVal))
```

Comment: Hi, dictionary keys should be unique.

Comment: Is there any other possibility to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this fulfils your requirement:

```
first_column = ['AB', 'AD', 'AB*AF', 'CD*EG', 'CG*AB']
second_column = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'H']

d = {}
for index, item in enumerate(first_column):
    for key in item.split('*'):
        if key in d:
            d[key].append(second_column[index])
        else:
            d[key] = [second_column[index]]
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'AB': ['A', 'D', 'H'],
 'AD': ['B'],
 'AF': ['D'],
 'CD': ['E'],
 'EG': ['E'],
 'CG': ['H']}
```